# Send e-mail automatically to next person

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to write a code but with no avail for the following problem:

I have a set of people who use a database. So everyone puts the time of the day for which they want to use it for e.g.:

```
Team member      Time            mail ID
ABC              1 pm - 2 pm     ABC@de.com
XYZ              3 pm - 4 pm     YXV@de.com
```

I want that if ABC finishes his work before 2 i.e. at 1:30 pm and if he updates the same on the sheet which is on the server and saves it, the next person due to use the database gets a mail stating that he has that extra 30 mins for the same.

Also, even if ABC finishes on time only i.e. at 2 XYZ should be able to get a reminder of his turn.

Another situation can be if ABC extend his session in the excel, XYZ gets a due indication in mail of the same in order to check and change his time slot.

I don't want everyone on the list to get the e-mail, only the person next in que.

Thanks in advance.

Sats

Comment: What code did you get and what is wrong with the code? This is a bit too broad as is.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please add the spreadsheet you are working with so far, as others may be able to provide you with more direction.

2) Here is code snippet to send email via vba in excel to someone; it uses outlook on users desktop to send email.

Sub SendEmail(ByVal strTo as string, ByVal strCC as string, ByVal strSubject As String, ByVal strBody As String, Optional ByVal strHTMLBody As String = "")

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCC
    .subject = strSubject
    If strBody <> "" Then
        .body = strBody
    Else
        .HTMLBody = strHTMLBody
    End If
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    '.Send    ' if you want to send immediately
    .Display  ' if you want the user to see the email before sending it manually.

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

3) Defining the workflow will require some additional VBA programming which depends on how you have your spreadsheet setup.

Hope this helps.